# How to use 2 mixins in State in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a state class

```
class ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen>...
```

And I want to use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin (to prevent the TabBar that holds these screens from disposing of) and TickerProviderStateMixin because I have the animation controller that requires it. But when I put both mixins in this class there's an error:

```
error: Type parameters could not be inferred for the mixin 'TickerProviderStateMixin' because the base class implements the mixin's supertype constraint 'State<T>' in multiple conflicting ways (mixin_inference_inconsistent_matching_classes at [myapp] lib/trips/ListScreen.dart:21)
```

I couldn't really find a good explanation of how to use mixins in one class. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';    

class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListScreenState();
  }
}

 class ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, TickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250), vsync: this);

  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Dart specifically complains about adding TickerProviderStateMixin. If I remove AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, then it doesn't complain anymore.

Comment: Please show the code that produces this error.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
class ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => null;

}
```

Comment: This works, only if I remove TickerProviderStateMixin

Comment: What do you mean with "works" or "does not work"? I added this code to my app and it didn't complain.

Comment: Please also add the code of the `ListScreen` class declaration.

Comment: It gives me an error: Type parameters could not be inferred for the mixin 'TickerProviderStateMixin' because the base class implements the mixin's supertype constraint 'State<T>' in multiple conflicting ways (mixin_inference_inconsistent_matching_classes at [myapp] lib/trips/ListScreen.dart:21)

Comment: Is this error from the analyzer or do you get it only at runtime? What flutter version are you using? (`flutter --version`).

Comment: It is from analyser. Version of flutter is: Flutter 0.8.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5ab9e70727 (6 weeks ago) • 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
Engine • revision 58a1894a1c
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

Comment: Can you try with `beta v0.9.4`?

Comment: It worked with v0.9.4! I didn't even think of it, because tried it a month or two ago and it didn't work with older versions. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear! Was a since fixed Dart bug then.

Answer (score 18):

For anyone coming here using `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`, simply remove the `Single` from the name.